# How to reuse input value

Tags: java

```
public double getInput() {
    System.out.print("Percentage of attacks that will be aimed low: ");
        Scanner data = new Scanner(System.in);
    double low = data.nextDouble();
    return(low);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < round ; i++) {
        xxxx.getInput();
    }
```

I didn't include all of it, but I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? What to you mean by "its does not work"? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: `low` has no type specified

Comment: You forgot the type of your variable. It should be `final int low`.

Comment: @user3230613 `getInput()` needs to be static for this example to work. You would also have to define `data` as a static global variable outside of a method in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use `final`, you must write the type of variable like this `final int` or `final double`.

In your program you should have:

```
final int low = data.nextInt();
```

from  your new code

i think you want  to reuse the first entered value without asking the user input again

this is the method

```
 public static double getInput(int i) {   


if(i==0)
   {
    System.out.print("Percentage of attacks that will be aimed low: ");}


    Scanner data = new Scanner(System.in);
double low = data.nextDouble();
return(low);
```

}

and this is the main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {



     for ( int i = 0 ; i < round ; i++) {
 getInput(i); }
```

}

Comment: @user3230613 my brother, can you explain which value you want reuse? .... in your comment above (I want to reuse the first entered value without asking the user input again)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to put `final` in front of it, it will get the first `int` specified, and as it's not in a `for` loop, the value will *never* change unless you change it yourself. However, you haven't declared the type of `low`. So do it like this:

```
int low = data.nextInt();
```

From your new code, you could try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner data = new Scanner(System.in);
    double low = data.nextDouble();
    // you have low now
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < round ; i++) {
        System.out.print("Percentage of attacks that will be aimed low: ");
        // do what you want with low
    }
```

Comment: yes I forgot to put that. But my question how to make the loop reuse the input value without running scanner class again?

Comment: @user3230613 It should do that already... you also forgot to declare the type of `height` as an `int`. It will reuse the input value, however, it will overwrite `height` on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Agreed. Unless you are using this code in a loop which you haven't shown, your scanner will not be recreated.

Comment: actually my code is different than the one above. I have a loop that will run a method which will ask the user input. For each run, the loop will call that method and ask the user input again. I want to reuse the first entered value without asking the user input again. I just edited , can you check it?

Comment: You still aren't showing all the relevant code. Where do you define `data`?

Comment: I just added scanner class

Comment: @user3230613 See my updated answer. Honestly, you don't need the method, as that can just be put in `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a local variable outside the loop in that method, and set its value to the result of a `getInput()` call. Then you can reuse that value in the loop as many times as you want.

Like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
double temp = xxxx.getInput();
for ( int i = 0 ; i < round ; i++) {
    //whatever operation you were going to do on the value
}
```

EDIT: put something like `private double userInput` as the instance variable and then either set it from the main method or create a `setUserInput()` setter method to change its value. I would recommend the second one just so you can have some separation.

EDIT 2:

```
public class Example() 
{
private double userInput; //This is the instance variable
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
}
}
```

then you could create another method like this

```
private setInput(double inputIn) {
this.userInput = inputIn;
}
```

this would be called from your main method. The parameter to send this method would be the return value from the `getInput()` call

EDIT 3: Sorry for so many edits but I keep thinking about things. You will also want to create a simple getter method also just so there will be a specific way to get the value. See below:

```
private getUserInput() {
return this.userInput;
}
```

Comment: is there other way? I can't do this because I am using many methods.

Comment: Do you need to use the input across many methods? In that case I would declare an instance variable, and then instantiate it once the user enters a value.

Comment: you will put them right under your class declaration and before your first method. They will be variables for the entire class. I will make another EDIT

Comment: Hopefully my edits help! I know there is a lot, but it is a lot easier to make a setter and getter than to have to get input ever time.